# Stata - descriptive statistic for Panel data

Tags: count, statistics, latex, stata, summary

I am trying to create a table showing the number of neighborhoods and metropolitan areas for each year of my (unbalanced) panel data set. I would like something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y43V9.png)

Also, I would like to display the number of coastal neighborhoods (I have a dummy indicating the coastal status of the neighborhood) on another columns.

I have tried this code,

`tabout year   if tr_pop>0 & pri!=. using "$results/table1/table1.tex",  stats(count summ i_shore)   style(tex)  replace   f(0c )  clab(Neighborhoods)`

but I only got one columns about the number of neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float(year metro nhood)
2010 1 1
2010 1 2
2010 2 3
2020 1 1
2020 1 2
2020 2 3
2020 3 4
end

egen tagm = tag(year metro)
egen metros = total(tagm), by(year)
egen tagn = tag(year nhood)
egen nhoods = total(tagn), by(year)

tabdisp year, c(metros nhoods)

----------------------------------
     year |     metros      nhoods
----------+-----------------------
     2010 |          2           3
     2020 |          3           4
----------------------------------

.
```

With a `coastal` (0, 1) indicator (dummy in vulgar parlance) you might just want an extra variable defined by `total(coastal * tagn)`.

If each neighbourhood occurs just once in the data for each year (we can't see your data) you can go direct to

```
bysort year : gen nhoods = _N
```

Comment: Thanks, it work perfectly.
Is there a solution to export this table to latex using a log file or something else ?

Comment: Probably, but you'll need to hope that someone else writes that code.